Romantic Comedy help?
I can't remember the name of a romantic comedy that I saw fairly recently. I can not think of any of the actors, but the plot is essentially a girl runs into an obnoxious kid from high school selling driftwood in the park. Her and her boyfriend (who is a Dbag) decide that she should take him to a family event to make the real boyfriend look better. The family is well-to-do, and it may take place in the Hamptons. There is a grandfather in the movie who fakes not being able to talk (he does talk later). The obnoxious guy drives a van that runs on vegetable oil. There is a sister who wants to be a singer, but affraid to tell her parents...that is about all that i remember. Any help would be great. 

I think It's - Surprised by Love (2015)

The story of a young businesswoman who tries to convince her uptight parents to accept her current boyfriend and instead finds herself falling for an old high school flame.

IMDB - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4016588/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3
